# Ruby: Find all occurrences of a pattern in a string, manipulate, and then replace

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a way to search for all occurrences of a pattern in a string, perform some nontrivial manipulation of the string returned, and then replace it.

Ruby's [String#gsub!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) method isn't a good fit because I need to take the returned occurrence and then manipulate it to come up with the value that will be used to replace it.

Ruby's [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method, of course, can be used to find all occurrences of the pattern but I'm not sure how to replace the returned occurrences once I've made the necessary changes to them.

The code example below is not what I'm actually working on demonstrates the sort of thing I'm attempting to accomplish.

```
# String
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

# Look for all words that start with a vowel
string.scan(/\s[aeiou]\w{1,}/i).each do |word|

    # Manipulate the words that match the pattern
    word.upcase

    # Replace the word in the string with the manipulated value
    # Need some help here
end

# Print the modified string
puts string
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with a block, so

```
string.gsub(/\s[aeiou]\w{1,}/i) do |word|
  word.upcase
end
```

Comment: Or `gsub(/\s[aeiou]\w{1,}/i, &:upcase)` if `upcase` is all that's really being used.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) can be used with a block, which is passed the matched string. The block's result is then used to replace the match:

```
# String
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

string.gsub!(/\s[aeiou]\w{1,}/i) { |m| m.upcase }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like that:

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
copy = string
# Look for all words that start with a vowel
string.scan(/\s[aeiou]\w{1,}/i).each do |word|

    # Manipulate the words that match the pattern
    copy.gsub! word, word.upcase

end

# Print the modified string
puts copy
```

Comment: No, only `\b` that is a word boundary ( a cesure between a word and a non word character), adding a quantifier doesn't have any sense

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte does that mean that two consecutive spaces are considered as one `\b` ?

Comment: No `\b` is a zero-width assertion. it marks only the border between a character that is in the `\w` character class and a character that is not in this class (but doesn't match any character).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `gsub`:

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."

string.split.map {|word| "aeiou".include?(word[0]) ? word.capitalize : word}.join(' ')
  # => "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetur Adipisicing Elit."
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize that there are probably better ways to accomplish what I gave in that example. It's really completely unrelated to what I'm working on though and I only provided it as simple example to solve the more complex problem I'm working on.